# JQuery val returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, undefined

So I'm calling the following function:

```
function updateOutput(a){

    var n = $('#selector').val();

    $('#hueslide').val(a[n].hue);
    $('#huetext').val(a[n].hue);
}
```

And I'm getting an error: "Cannot read property 'hue' of undefined."

However, when I use console.log(n), it's returning a value. And when I manually insert the same value in a[n], I get the expected result. I'm guessing this is an asynchronous issue, but the same code was working in an earlier version and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Specifically, when trying to debug  updateOutput using console.log, I get the following:

```
console.log(n); //returns 0
console.log(a); //returns an array of objects
console.log(a[0]); //returns first object in array
console.log(a(n)); // returns undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Turns out the value of `0` in `n` I was passing a `string`. So adding `n = parseInt(n);` resolved the issue.

Comment: So does it work? Aha Good. Now **Accept your answer**.

Answer (score 3):

That error isn't saying that `n` is undefined, or even `a`, it's saying that there is no property `hue` on whatever is assigned to `a[n]`. Whatever you are passing into `updateOutput` has no key to match `n` that also has the property `hue`.

Comment: So the weird thing is that when I manually pass in the value of n (in this case 0) it works. So that

    function updateOutput(a){

        var n = $('#selector').val();

        $('#hueslide').val(a[0].hue);
        $('#huetext').val(a[0].hue);
    }

Returns the values I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
function updateOutput(a){

   $(document).ready(function(e) {

        var n = $('#selector').val();

       $('#hueslide').val(a[n].hue);
       $('#huetext').val(a[n].hue);


    });  
}
```

You have to wait until the element are fully loaded. That's why you have to use ready method.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work either. I'm going to edit my Question to show the full code in context.